# React - Calling API after onclick

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my React app I have a button, which on clicking I'm calling a function to make a API request, however I see `Uncaught (in promise) Error` error.

I'm wondering whether I'm doing what I am in the correct way.

I've used `useEffect` in the past when the page loads to call an API, but not sure how to do this on a button click.

So in the render I have:

```
<Fab onClick={approveIt}>Go</Fab>
```

Then that function - which sits within the function component itself:

```
const [success, setSuccess] = React.useState(false);

function approveIt() {

   axios.post(api, {}).then(response => {
      // Simplified - lets just get the response
      console.log(response.status)

      // And set some state
      setSuccess(true);
   });

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You're doing it mostly right. Just not sure what the error it is. You can add a `.catch(err) { console.log(err) }` to the end of that promise to check.

Comment: @hackape right idea, but that is invalid syntax

Comment: Cool, so I don't need some nested `useEffect` (which from what I read is not allowed) or some other async/await/promise business

Comment: @userMod2 nope that's not necessary, you just need to make sure to add a `catch` handler for errors that may occur

Comment: Cool - that did the trick. Wa wondering whether i was missing something more fundamental. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to a `try, catch` statement, you have to add a `.catch` to your `axios.post` call in case an error occurs, in order to handle it. You could do something like this:

```
axios.post(api, {}).then(response => {
      // Simplified - lets just get the response
      console.log(response.status)

      // And set some state
      setSuccess(true);
   })
   .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      setSuccess(false);
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably an error in your axios call and you're not catching it. You can fix it this way:

```
  axios.post(api, {})
    .then(response => {
      // Simplified - lets just get the response
      console.log(response.status)

      // And set some state
      setSuccess(true);
    })
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error); })
```